# Trying to show most selling products in last week in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display the most selling products on homepage in WooCommerce but somehow it just doesnt work. My code is:

```php
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'date_query'     => array(
      array(
        'after'     => '1 week ago',
        'inclusive' => true,
      ),
    ),
  );

  $products = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($products->have_posts()) {
    while ($products->have_posts()) {
      $products->the_post();
      the_title();
    }
  } else {
    echo 'No products found';
  }

  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For That, You need to modify your data query. because you need to show the most selling in the last week and you are using the 1 month ago in data query.

Hear is Updated Code:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'date_query'     => array(
    array(
      'after'     => '1 week ago',
      'inclusive' => true,
    ),
  ),
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);

if ($products->have_posts()) {
  while ($products->have_posts()) {
    $products->the_post();
    the_title();
  }
} else {
  echo 'No products found';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Last week thing nor working, nor last month. It just doesnt work. I suspect that it's a server or PHP issue but couldnt figure out yet.